# Lightning Data Service not showing Validation Rule Errors

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-data-service

As part of Salesforce's low code policy, I have been tasked to remove some apex code which simply updates a field within a try catch. If a validation rule occurs, it is caught and I process the result in my JavaScript controller.

Using LDS, I want to update a Boolean field (checkbox) and display any validation error messages to the user. However my current code does not do this.

Cmp File

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >

<aura:attribute name="oppRecord" type="Object"/>
<aura:attribute name="recordSaveError" type="String" default=""/>

<!-- Load record in EDIT mode -->
<force:recordData aura:id="recordLoader"
    recordId="{!v.recordId}"
    layoutType="FULL"
    targetFields="{!v.oppRecord}"
    targetError="{!v.recordSaveError}"
    mode="EDIT" 
    recordUpdated="{!c.handleRecordUpdated}" />



    <div class="Edit opp">
    <lightning:card iconName="action:edit" title="Edit opp">
        <div class="slds-p-horizontal--small">                 
             <lightning:input label="Boolean field" type="checkbox" value="{!v.oppRecord.boolField}"/>            
              <br/>
            <lightning:button label="Save opp" variant="brand" onclick="{!c.saveOpp}" />
        </div>
   </lightning:card>
   </div>

    <!-- Display error message -->
    <aura:if isTrue="{!not(empty(v.recordSaveError))}">
      <div class="recordSaveError">
        {!v.recordSaveError}</div>
    </aura:if>

</aura:component>
```

JS Controller

```
({
saveOpp : function(component, event, helper) {
    if(component.get("v.oppRecord.boolField") == true){
        alert("Already true!");
        $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();            
    }
    else{
        var recordLoader = component.find("recordLoader");
        recordLoader.saveRecord($A.getCallback(function(saveResult) {
            if (saveResult.state === "ERROR") {
                var errMsg = "";
                // saveResult.error is an array of errors, 
                // so collect all errors into one message
                for (var i = 0; i < saveResult.error.length; i++) {
                    errMsg += saveResult.error[i].message + "\n";
                }
                alert(errMsg);
                component.set("v.recordSaveError", errMsg);
            } else if (saveResult.state === "SUCCESS" || saveResult.state === "DRAFT") {
                component.set("v.recordSaveError", "");
            }
                else{
                    alert("Unknown Error");
                }    
        }));             
    }        
},


// Control the component behavior here when record is changed (via any component)
handleRecordUpdated: function(component, event, helper) {
    var eventParams = event.getParams();
    if(eventParams.changeType === "CHANGED") {
        //reload page
        component.find("recordLoader").reloadRecord();
        $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();
        // get the fields that are changed for this record
        var changedFields = eventParams.changedFields;
        alert('Fields that are changed: ' + JSON.stringify(changedFields));
        // record is changed so refresh the component (or other component logic)
        var resultsToast = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
        resultsToast.setParams({
            "title": "Saved",
            "message": "The record was updated."
        });
        resultsToast.fire();
    } else if(eventParams.changeType === "LOADED") {
        alert("eventParams.changeType === LOADED");
        // record is loaded in the cache
    } else if(eventParams.changeType === "REMOVED") {
        // record is deleted and removed from the cache
        alert("eventParams.changeType === REMOVED");
    } else if(eventParams.changeType === "ERROR") {
        alert('Error: ' + component.get("v.error"));
    }
}
})
```

For example, if the Opportunity was in in Sale Stages 1-4, a validation rule error should appear. I am unsure how to process these types of errors.