# validation rule LightningComponent

Tags: lightning-aura-components

how can I capture and display validation rule error with a lightning component?

I have a path component that si updating a picklist field.

I want this to display the validation error instead of "There was a problem updating the record.".

````
<lightning:notificationsLibrary aura:id="notifLib"/>

<!--Picklist Field Attribute-->

<aura:attribute name="picklistField" type="object"/>

<!--Force Record Data to update picklist value-->

<force:recordData aura:id="record"

fields="Compass_Stage__c"

recordId="{!v.recordId}"

targetFields="{!v.picklistField}"

mode="EDIT"/>

<!--For changing from left-to-right use dir="ltr" and from to right-to-left use dir="rtl"-->

<div dir="ltr">

<!--Lightning Picklist Path For Applicatin Status-->

<lightning:picklistPath recordId="{!v.recordId}"

variant="linear"

picklistFieldApiName="Compass_Stage__c"

onselect="{!c.handleSelect}" />

</div>

</aura:component> 





({

handleSelect : function (component, event, helper) {

//get selected Status value

var selectStatus = event.getParam("detail").value;

//set selected Status value

component.set("v.picklistField.Compass_Stage__c", selectStatus);

component.find("record").saveRecord($A.getCallback(function(response) {

if (response.state === "SUCCESS") {

$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();

component.find('notifLib').showToast({

"variant": "success",

"message": "Record was updated sucessfully",

"mode" : "sticky"

});

} else {

component.find('notifLib').showToast({

"variant": "error",

"message": "There was a problem updating the record.",

"mode" : "sticky"

});

}

}));

}

})```
````

Comment: I think this article can help you : https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/221941/lightning-data-service-not-showing-validation-rule-errors

Comment: Also this is described in this Trailhead module: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lightning_data_service/lightning_data_service_handle_notifications